# Why won't the format function work with the algorithm for pi

Tags: python, format, pi

This is not my code it is example code from this website: https://github.com/karan/Projects/blob/master/Numbers/pi.py

```
# Find PI to the Nth Digit

from math import *

digits = raw_input('Enter number of digits to round PI to: ')

# print ('{0:.%df}' % min(20, int(digits))).format(math.pi) # nested string formatting

# calculate pi using Machin-like Formula
print ('{0:.%df}' % min(30, int(digits))).format(4 * (4 * atan(1.0/5.0) - atan(1.0/239.0)))
```

When I run it I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/pi.py", line 7, in <module>
    print ('{0:.%df}' % min(30, int(num))).format(4 * (4 * atan(1.0/5.0) - atan(1.0/239.0)))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Is this possibly a problem with the version of python I am using (3.4.0) Perhaps it is not compatible with this old code?

Comment: It means that your input wasn't convertible to `int`, so `None` was returned instead of a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a problem with your python version. Add an external pair of parenthesis:

```
print(
    ('{0:.%df}' % min(30, int(digits))).format(4 * (4 * atan(1.0/5.0) - atan(1.0/239.0)))
 )
```

This is because in python3 `print` is a function and that expression is parsed as:

```
(print('{0:.%df}' % min(30, int(digits)))).format(...)
```

In other words  `print` gets a single argument which is:

```
'{0:.%df}' % min(30, int(digits))
```

and the `.format` is called on the return value of the `print` call which is always `None`.

In python2, where `print` is a statement, everything is passed as an argument to the *statement* and thus the outer parenthesis aren't required.

---

Side note: you can avoid using the `%` formatting, since you can nest the formattings:

```
print('{0:.{1}f}'.format(4 * (4 * atan(1.0/5.0) - atan(1.0/239.0)), min(30, int(digits))))
```

Or maybe better:

```
print('{value:.{prec}f}'.format(prec=min(30, int(digits)), value=4 * (4 * atan(1.0/5.0) - atan(1.0/239.0))))
```